# Aligning bar in of histogram in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I tried to plot histogram with `bins = 5` and `x-axis` limit within minimum and maximum value of the data. Basically, first bin should start from minimum value of data and end at `min + (max-min)/bins`. Similarly second bin should start from `min + (max-min)/bins` and end at `min + 2*(max-min)/bins` and so on. I am able to break `x-axis` as I wish however unable to bin and place the data in desired cuts. I am unable to get what am I missing. This is what I have tried.

```
attach(mtcars)

x_break = seq(min(mtcars$mpg), max(mtcars$mpg), length.out = 6)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg))
p1 <- p1 + geom_histogram(bins = 5, closed = "left", color = "white", center = 1)
p1 <- p1 + theme_bw()
p1 <- p1 + scale_x_continuous(breaks = x_break)
p1
```

This is what I got. I want each bar placed well between pair of numbers.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `breaks` parameter directly to `geom_histogram`:

```
p1 <- p1 + geom_histogram(bins = 5, closed = "left", color = "white", breaks = x_break)
```